# Creating segmented line connecting points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have a series of points along a road that I want to use to separate plots. I have tried using the point to line tool to create a line from these points using QGIS. However, it creates a single line with no attributes to separate each segment.

Is there a way to create separate lines for each segment (each straight section would be its own line)?

[image: I started with the points. This is the line that I created. I would like the line between each point to be separate from each other line.]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table?

Answer (score 2):

Use the QGIS ***PointsToPaths*** plugin (note the plural "paths").  It will create a separate line segment for each sequential pair of points.  Additionally, each new line segment will contain the attributes from the two points that defined it.  For details, see my answer at:
[Creating line layer from point layer with start and end attributes in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408615/creating-line-layer-from-point-layer-with-start-and-end-attributes-in-qgis/409183#409183)

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS, you can use the `Split Lines at Points` tool. the tool is located under the `Processing toolbox → SAGA → Feature - Lines → Split Lines at Points` .

[image]

You need to use a small Epsilon value such as `0.001` to make sure the line will be split at each point

Before using the tool

[image]

After using the tool

[image]